# Understanding I/O disk accesses from docker container

Tags: linux, docker, filesystems, storage, block-device

As we know in docker there exists something like storage-driver (like devicemapper, overlay2 and so on). 
There exists some thing that I don't understand:
Container can access to volume or its own filesystem.

**How is it possible** that docker storage driver can intercept such request of I/O access? After all, code of storage driver must do the work, however, container is like process, so requests should be processed by OS. On the other hand, these requests must be processed by storage driver (after all, it may require some diving into deeper layers and so on).

Does it mean that each I/O request is processes by storage driver? How is it possible?  What about accesses to volumes?

Comment: The Linux kernel is heavily involved (which is part of why you can't run modern Docker on CentOS 6, or non-Linux Unices like the BSDs or MacOS).  Is there a more specific question about your application in particular that the SO community could answer?

Comment: How does it happen that storage driver can intercept IO request?